# Problem with a tableview

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

this is the delegate method of a tableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (check == TRUE){


}
```

Check is a bool value, then I want that if check is true, it should skip the creation of a cell.
How can I do?

Comment: The problem is that the cellForRowAtindexpath must return a UITableCell sow if youdon't return a cell your app will probably crash You need to go back at the table source delegate and set the number of rows to the desired one and give a datasource that has only the data you desire

Comment: This doesn't make sense. What should the table display when you don't give one?

Comment: you do know about cell reuse, do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point you can't, you HAVE to return a cell from that method otherwise you get an exception. The key is to do the check before returning the number of rows in the section....

Comment: then an other solution may be add a value to indexPath.row no?

Comment: At the point you return the number of sections and rows per section you should know what data you wish to show so you return the relevant counts. When the table view asks you for data at a particular section / row combination you should be able to return what it wants. I normally filter my data depending on what I want to show, return the counts of the filtered data and also use that filtered data to return the correct cell.

Answer (score 0):

Cell creation is depend on numberOfRowsInSection method return 0 when you don't want any cell.

Answer (score 0):

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{

```
return value;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Hum, according to the UITableView Reference:

> **cellForRowAtIndexPath:**
>
> Returns the table cell at the specified index path.
>
> ```
> - (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
> ```
>
> (...)
>
> **Return Value**
>
> An object representing a cell of the table or **nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range**.

So you should be just fine returning nil, and the cell will be hidden, I guess.

Is this what you want?

Comment: Sadly if the tableview THINKS the cell is visible returning nil will cause an exception. The correct way to handle this is to only return a row count that matches the number of cells you DO wish to show.

Comment: If you implement the datasource then you must return a value, if however you call this method yourself you may get nil back as per the docs

Comment: Ok, sorry. Misinterpreted the Reference. :/

Comment: Not at all, it is confusing, the idea that if you override the method you have to do one thing but the default behaviour if you call it is something else... bizarre and confusing!